# inverse fourier transform of the fourier transform

Tags: python, fft

with scipy fftpack I calculated the inverse fourier transform of a fourier transform, therefore I should get my original function. However, I'm getting values close to the original ones, and complex, the original ones were real.

the complex parts are near zero, but are not zero in general. Is this normal? I would kind of expect so since the computer cannot be fully precise when performing these calculations.

Is there any way to improve the precision?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and show us what you want, what you're currently getting, or your current error message, and what you've tried so far, also see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also see [How to write a perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question)

Comment: Yes, this is normal. Unless you use a function that specifically outputs a real-valued function, the output of the IFFT will be complex, and values very close to zero are normal floating-point rounding errors. The only way to improve precision is to use a more precise float (ie more bits). In general you shouldn’t need this.